# Retrieve array of video IDs from youtube playlist ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, youtube

I want to retrieve an array of video ID's using a youtube playlist ID.

Basicually a function `getPlaylist(playlist)` that returns

```
[{'title':'Video1 Title', 'ID':'Video1 ID'},
{'title':'Video2 Title', 'ID':'Video2 ID'},
{'title':'Video3 Title', 'ID':'Video3 ID'}];
```

I currently have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cG8N4/2/), but making it return data in an array would require a major rewrite, and I'm not sure how to approach it.

I want to be able to do var stuff = `getPlaylist(ID);`, and reference the entered ID like `stuff[4].title` and so, and easily handle the response in for loops etc.

I want to do this with as few lines of code as possible, and without libraries and API's (like jQuery and the youtube javascript API).

Comment: Why not just `push` the `videoID` into and `Array` in your loop?

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. I might be doing something wrong though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable outside of the loop

```
var arrayOfvideoIDs = [];
```

inside your loop

```
for (....) {
    ...
    list_data += '<li>'+videoID+'</li>';
    arrayOfvideoIDs.push(videoID);
}
```

You now have an array of `videoID`s